# How to select corresponding value in a row when aggregating with max() in clickhouse?

Tags: sql, database, clickhouse

I have a table in db like this:

This is a part for one UserID, but in fact there are many of them.

```
create table MY_TABLE
(
    UserID Nullable(String),
    OID int,
    TotalHits Nullable(int),
    DaysOfHits Nullable(int),
    UniqPrimaryEvents Nullable(int)
)
engine = Memory;

insert into MY_TABLE (UserID, OID, TotalHits, DaysOfHits, UniqPrimaryEvents) values ('1000c666-04db-4447-9ea1-ecf1e2275c81', 6564023, 4, 1, 0);
insert into MY_TABLE (UserID, OID, TotalHits, DaysOfHits, UniqPrimaryEvents) values ('1000c666-04db-4447-9ea1-ecf1e2275c81', 6546504, 9, 1, 0);
insert into MY_TABLE (UserID, OID, TotalHits, DaysOfHits, UniqPrimaryEvents) values ('1000c666-04db-4447-9ea1-ecf1e2275c81', 6538286, 12, 2, 0);
insert into MY_TABLE (UserID, OID, TotalHits, DaysOfHits, UniqPrimaryEvents) values ('1000c666-04db-4447-9ea1-ecf1e2275c81', 6536273, 8, 2, 0);
insert into MY_TABLE (UserID, OID, TotalHits, DaysOfHits, UniqPrimaryEvents) values ('1000c666-04db-4447-9ea1-ecf1e2275c81', 6534195, 57, 6, 0);
insert into MY_TABLE (UserID, OID, TotalHits, DaysOfHits, UniqPrimaryEvents) values ('1000c666-04db-4447-9ea1-ecf1e2275c81', 6528643, 4, 1, 0);
insert into MY_TABLE (UserID, OID, TotalHits, DaysOfHits, UniqPrimaryEvents) values ('1000c666-04db-4447-9ea1-ecf1e2275c81', 6496311, 7, 2, 0);
insert into MY_TABLE (UserID, OID, TotalHits, DaysOfHits, UniqPrimaryEvents) values ('1000c666-04db-4447-9ea1-ecf1e2275c81', 6492524, 7, 1, 0);
insert into MY_TABLE (UserID, OID, TotalHits, DaysOfHits, UniqPrimaryEvents) values ('1000c666-04db-4447-9ea1-ecf1e2275c81', 6475804, 9, 1, 0);
insert into MY_TABLE (UserID, OID, TotalHits, DaysOfHits, UniqPrimaryEvents) values ('1000c666-04db-4447-9ea1-ecf1e2275c81', 6424164, 5, 1, 0);
insert into MY_TABLE (UserID, OID, TotalHits, DaysOfHits, UniqPrimaryEvents) values ('1000c666-04db-4447-9ea1-ecf1e2275c81', 6403817, 8, 1, 0);
insert into MY_TABLE (UserID, OID, TotalHits, DaysOfHits, UniqPrimaryEvents) values ('1000c666-04db-4447-9ea1-ecf1e2275c81', 6403592, 9, 1, 0);
insert into MY_TABLE (UserID, OID, TotalHits, DaysOfHits, UniqPrimaryEvents) values ('1000c666-04db-4447-9ea1-ecf1e2275c81', 6400394, 13, 1, 0);
insert into MY_TABLE (UserID, OID, TotalHits, DaysOfHits, UniqPrimaryEvents) values ('1000c666-04db-4447-9ea1-ecf1e2275c81', 6383627, 8, 1, 0);
insert into MY_TABLE (UserID, OID, TotalHits, DaysOfHits, UniqPrimaryEvents) values ('1000c666-04db-4447-9ea1-ecf1e2275c81', 6364163, 4, 1, 0);
insert into MY_TABLE (UserID, OID, TotalHits, DaysOfHits, UniqPrimaryEvents) values ('1000c666-04db-4447-9ea1-ecf1e2275c81', 6349018, 7, 1, 0);
insert into MY_TABLE (UserID, OID, TotalHits, DaysOfHits, UniqPrimaryEvents) values ('1000c666-04db-4447-9ea1-ecf1e2275c81', 6270551, 6, 1, 0);
```

I need to aggregate the table, and have in results both results of agg funcs and corresponding value from OID:

I'm doing smth like:

```
SELECT
    UserID,
    uniq(OID) AS UniqObjects,
    sum(TotalHits) AS TotalHits,
    round(avg(DaysOfHits), 2) AS AvgObjectHitDays,
    max(DaysOfHits) AS MaxHitPeriod,
-- here I need OID corresponding to max(DaysOfHits) value
    round((avg(DaysOfHits) / max(DaysOfHits)) * 100, 2) AS PerOfMaxHit
```

I tried smth like  `anyIf(OID, DaysOfHits = max(DaysOfHits)),` but you can't have agg func inside agg func.

PS the source of Select is another joined select, not a single table.

Please, help!

Comment: Can you show us how you want your output to be in the desc?

Answer (score 1):

argMax is a great thing! And I'm just a beginner, sorry)

the answer is argMax(OID, DaysOfHits) - it will return OID for max of DaysOfHits, as was required

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).